# When uploading IFormFile file with minimalAPI in swagger, the file is null

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, asp.net-core-7.0, asp.net-minimal-apis

I'm trying to write a http post using minimal API in C# NetCore7, that recieves IFormFile file.

MinimalAPI:

```cs
 var group = app.MapGroup("Payment").WithTags("Payment").WithOpenApi();
group.MapPost("htmlToPdf", async (IFormFile file) =>
    {
       ....
       ...       
}).Accepts<IFormFile>("multipart/form-data");
```

When I upload the file by using swaggerUI, the file is null:

[image: SwaggerUI]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Do you have a [mre]? Can you please show how do you post the file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I post the file using SwaggerUI like in the Sceenshot i added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the following line:

```cs
var group = app.MapGroup("Payment").WithTags("Payment").WithOpenApi();
```

When i removed the following `WithOpenAPi()` extension, The uploading file is work properlly!

Comment: Okay but did you find a way to  use .WithOpenApi()? I want to add a description to my endpoint...